# Speech recognition module alsa error

Tags: sound, python, alsa, microphone, voice-recognition

I am trying to convert speech to text using SpeechRecognition on ubuntu 21.10

Here is the code

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def listen():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    mic = sr.Microphone(device_index=1)
    with mic as source:
        audio = r.listen(source, timeout=10)
        return r.recognize_google(audio)
print(listen())
```

This is throwing an error

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:877:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:877:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:877:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:877:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
Expression 'parameters->channelCount <= maxChans' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1514
Expression 'ValidateParameters( inputParameters, hostApi, StreamDirection_In )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2818
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/harsha/PycharmProjects/playground/audio.py", line 29, in <module>
    assitant.listen()
  File "/home/harsha/PycharmProjects/playground/audio.py", line 23, in listen
    with mic as source:
  File "/home/harsha/PycharmProjects/playground/sand/lib/python3.9/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 138, in __enter__
    self.audio.open(
  File "/home/harsha/PycharmProjects/playground/sand/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 750, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/harsha/PycharmProjects/playground/sand/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 441, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
OSError: [Errno -9998] Invalid number of channels
```

I am doing this in my laptop with inbuilt microphone.